# Gnuplot and C - plot different symbols/colors

Tags: c, gnuplot

I would like to plot different points with different colors and symbols. Here is my Code in "C" :

```
float x[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
float y[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};

FILE *gnuplot = popen("gnuplot", "w");

fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-' pt 7 pointsize 2 lc \"blue\" notitle \n");

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {

    fprintf(gnuplot,"%f %f\n", x[i], y[i]);
}

fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-' pt 5 pointsize 2 lc \"red\" notitle \n");

for (int i = 6; i < 12; ++i) {

    fprintf(gnuplot,"%f %f\n", x[i], y[i]);
}

fprintf(gnuplot, "e\n");
fflush(gnuplot);
getch();
fclose(gnuplot);
```

Unfortunately, all points have the same type and same color. What is my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

[Result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1UsZ.png)

All points are blue and have the pointtype 7 and the pointsize 2. The second command line to change the style has no effect:

```
    fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-' pt 5 pointsize 2 lc \"red\" notitle \n");
```

Comment: Do the same commands produce the expected result if used in command-line?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which points are plotted and which pointtype and color do they have. Please edit your question and post an image of your resulting graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is like the following:

```
plot '-' pt 7 ps 2 lc "blue" notitle
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
plot '-' pt 6 ps 2 lc "red" notitle
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10   10
11   11
e
```

For inline data, i.e. special filename `'-'` the data is ended by a line `e`. Check `help special-filenames`.

So, your code will:

- plot x from 0 to 5 with blue filled circles
- the line `plot '-' pt 6 ps 2 lc "red" notitle` will be interpreted as data line because inline data has not yet been ended by a line `e`, hence, this line will be ignored because it does not contain numerical data
- plot x from 6 to 11 with blue filled circles

But it seems you want to have the following:

**Code:**

```
plot '-' pt 7 ps 2 lc "blue" notitle, \
     '-' pt 6 ps 2 lc "red"  notitle
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
e
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10   10
11   11
e
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition**: (as mentioned in the comments)

Since gnuplot 5.0 you have datablocks which are including the data as well into the plotting code, check `help inline`.
The advantage is that if you want to make plots of several columns you don't have to provide the data multiple times or split it into sequential 2 column data.
The following examples will all result in the same plot:

**Code:**

```
$Data1 <<EOD
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
EOD

$Data1 <<EOD
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10   10
11   11
EOD

plot $Data1 u 1:2 w p pt 7, \
     $Data2 u 1:2 w p pt 5
```

```
$Data <<EOD
0    0    6    6
1    1    7    7
2    2    8    8
3    3    9    9
4    4    10   10
5    5    11   11
EOD

plot $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7, \
        '' u 3:4 w p pt 5
```

```
plot '-' u 1:2 w p pt 7, \
     '-' u 1:2 w p pt 5,
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
e
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10   10
11   11
e
```

```
plot '-' u 1:2 w p pt 7, \
     '-' u 3:4 w p pt 5,
0    0    6    6
1    1    7    7
2    2    8    8
3    3    9    9
4    4    10   10
5    5    11   11
e
0    0    6    6
1    1    7    7
2    2    8    8
3    3    9    9
4    4    10   10
5    5    11   11
e
```

Comment: Sorry, should be pt 5 (filled squares) instead of pt 6 (open circles).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I just had to change it to `fprintf(gnuplot, "plot '-' pt 7 ps 2 lc \"blue\" notitle, \ '-' pt 5 pointsize 2 lc \"red\" notitle \n");` and add an extra `fprintf(gnuplot, "e\n");`.

Comment: By the way, I personally would prefer datablocks instead of `'-'`, because if you want to plot several columns, with `'-'` you have to repeat the data again. I will add a small example to my answer.